# How do I make a blinking effect in corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there any way I could make a ball, that blinks? I would like to use two colors, so it blinks first with one color, then the other. I have no idea how to do this.

```
local ball = display.newCircle(10,10,10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You checked Corona SDK [API Reference](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/blink.html) ?

To quote an example:

```
local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 )
transition.blink( square, { time=1000 } )
```

To address the second part of Your question, I guess, You could use `onStart` and `onRepeat` parameters. Changing the primary color accordingly to blink counter on start and increasing counter of blinks on repeat.